# No permission to access webApplication properties

Tags: sharepoint, exception, sharepoint-2010, permissions

When activating a site feature I automaticly want to set a WebApplication property. This is the code:

```
   public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {             
                SPWeb currentWeb = ContentTypes.ValidateFeatureActivation(properties);
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(currentWeb.Site.Url))
                {
                    SPWebApplication currentApplication = site.WebApplication;
                    if (currentApplication.MaxQueryLookupFields < 20)
                    {

                        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                currentApplication.MaxQueryLookupFields = 20;
                            }

                            catch (System.Security.SecurityException ex)
                            {
                                _log.ErrorFormat("no permission");
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }                
        }
```

Even if I a farm administrator activated the feature, the security exception is thrown ("access denied"). at line

```
currentApplication.MaxQueryLookupFields = 20;
```

AFAIK SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges runs as a site admin, **not** farm admin. But HOW can this be done? (WITHOUT RunWithElevatedPrivileges I get the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new SPSite, SPWeb and SPWebApplication objects inside the SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges otherwise you will be running them with the same permissions as the current user. E.g.

```
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
             {             
                SPWeb currentWeb = ContentTypes.ValidateFeatureActivation(properties);
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(currentWeb.Site.Url))
                {
                    SPWebApplication currentApplication = site.WebApplication;
                    if (currentApplication.MaxQueryLookupFields < 20)
                    {
                            try
                            {
                                currentApplication.MaxQueryLookupFields = 20;
                            }

                            catch (System.Security.SecurityException ex)
                            {
                                _log.ErrorFormat("no permission");
                            }


                    }
                }
            });                
        }
```

Comment: I tried **without** RunWithElevatedPrivilegues and logged in as a farm admin. Still got the error.
The problem is that RunWith.. executes as site admin, NOT farm admin. So I search for something "like" RunWith... but works with farm admin permissions

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate another SPSite object inside RWEP to get the application pool identity context because the first SPSite which is created outside the RWEP block is created with the SPSite current user context. So try this one:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        SPWeb currentWeb = ContentTypes.ValidateFeatureActivation(properties);
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(currentWeb.Site.Url))
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite _site = new SPSite(site.ID))
                {
                    SPWebApplication currentApplication = _site.WebApplication;
                    if (currentApplication.MaxQueryLookupFields < 20)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            currentApplication.MaxQueryLookupFields = 20;
                        }
                        catch (System.Security.SecurityException ex)
                        {
                            _log.ErrorFormat("no permission");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```